# No logro alinear al centro o a la derecha la etiqueta <th>

Tags: html, css

Estoy alineando una lista, he logrado alinear al centro y a la derecha los `<td>`, pero los `<th>` están rebeldes, les dejo mi código:

```
<h1>Productos Disponibles</h1>
<table style="width:90%" border="1">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>                <h4><%= "Nombre" %></h4></th>
      <th>                <h4><%= "Descripcion" %></h4></th>
      <th align="center" ><h4><%= "Existencia" %></h4></th>
      <th align="right" > <h4><%= "Precio" %></h4></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @productos.each do |producto| %>
      <tr>
          <td>                <h4><%= producto.nombre %></h4></td>
          <td>                <h4><%= producto.descripcion %></h4></td>
          <td align="center" ><h4><%= producto.cantidad_existencia %></h4></td>
          <td align="right" > <h4><%= producto.precio %></h4></td>

      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

una muestra de la salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo probé en codepen y con los snippets de SO y funciona.

Comment: pero modificaste algo del código? yo estoy empezando en esto de la programación, se que es codepen, snippets son pedazos de código, ok, pero SO??

Comment: SO = StackOverflow, me refiero a "este" sitio web. ¿Ya lo probaste en Codepen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. el atributo aling es obsoleto y no esta siendo soportado por html5,
   deberías en su lugar usar CSS
2. Los elementos `<th>` por defecto se encuentran en **negrilla** y centrados

En todo caso para alinear un texto debes usas la propiedad CSS

```
text-align: center|right|left
```

```html
<h1>Productos Disponibles</h1>
<table style="width:90%" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Descripcion</th>
      <th style="text-align: center">Existencia</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>    
      <tr>
          <td>nombre 1</td>
          <td>producto 1</td>
          <td style="text-align: center">10</td>
          <td style="text-align: right" >10.000</td>
      </tr>          
      <tr>
          <td>nombre 2</td>
          <td>producto 2</td>
          <td style="text-align: center">150</td>
          <td style="text-align: right" >36.500</td>
      </tr>  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Solo como por recomendación, asegurate de  tener esta etiqueta en la primera linea de tu salida html:

```
<!doctype html>
```

> El Doctype o “Declaración del tipo de documento” es una instrucción
>   especial que va al inicio de nuestro documento HTML y que permite al
>   navegador entender qué versión de HTML estamos utilizando... [Leer mas](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/doctype-que-es-y-para-que-sirve/)

Comment: Excelente nekoos

Comment: Amigo, me puedes decir porque tengo -1 en esta pregunta? que hice mal

Comment: Pues, la verdad yo no lo he puesto, supongo que la apreciación del votante es que le ha faltado algo, posiblemente porque tu código no aplica a la regla de [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Un voto negativo expresa que debes esforzarte por mejorar la pregunta o respuesta, fijate que en tu código usas `tags` incrustados de `ruby`, cuanto tu problema es expresamente de `html+css`. Ahora  fijate que en mi respuesta intente mostrar una salida estática de tu problema esto facilita que sea verificable. Si corriges esto quizás quien te califico mal retracte su apreciación. He incluso yo pueda asignarte un voto a favor por mejorar este aspecto. Sin embargo ten en cuenta que el criterio de votación es subjetivo a la apreciación de la persona que lo aplica.